# Calculation of dispersion energy in Gaussian 09

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

How can I calculate the dispersion energy using Gaussian 09? Where is it printed in the output file when using `wb97xd/cc-pvdz sp`? If it isn't printed by default, what flags can be used to turn printing on?

Comment: Depending on the functional you use, it either contains some dispersion correction or not. For those which do not you can manually add it with `EmpiricalDispersion=...` if it is parameterized. If not, you can specify the parameters via the command line. See the manual for detail. The omegaB97XD DFA already contains the dispersion; it is parametrized that way. You will not be able to find a value for the dispersion correction.

Answer (score 4):

The value of the empirical dispersion correction is printed when the print level is turned up using `#p` in the route line. For any method that contains an empirical dispersion correction, search for `R6Disp` or `Dispersion energy`, where other parts of the line will vary depending on the type of correction (-D2, -D3, or -D3(BJ)):

```
R6Disp:  Grimme-D2 Dispersion energy=       -0.0174233223 Hartrees.
```

This line is **not** printed with `#` or `#n` at the start of the route section.

For wavefunction methods that include dispersion via electron correlation, the dispersion contribution is non-separable. For a method like B2PLYP-D3, the printed "Dispersion energy" is the empirical correction, not the MP2 contribution!

Comment: This is very good to know and I have to admit I did not know about it. It is one of the neverending shortcomings of the Gaussian manual.